# improved bandwith at home by bonding or teaming mobile data and home internet (via utp cable)

Tags: networking

Working from home with kids and soon a spouse. So thinking of boosting my internet performance. I have broadband, nominally 100/40 bps but struggling with higher load.
And I have quite decent 4G bandwidth.
Ubuntu 18.04.4

Via an excellent tutorial here https://fedoramagazine.org/bond-wifi-and-ethernet-for-easier-networking-mobility/ I was able to bond my home ethernet and mobile hotspot.
Well, I think I was. As soon  as I got it working, I did a speed test and noticed no difference.

The default configuration in the tutorial is for "failover", so it's not surprising that there was no bandwidth improvement.

I quickly realised there is a lot I don't know.

1) Is is possible to bond two interfaces like this, which are each connected to different networks? I think it should be.

2) there are load sharing modes: round robin, and two adaptive modes. In practical terms for a single user on a laptop, do these actually have benefits?

I tried to use one  of the adaptive load sharing modes, but I didn't notice any speed test improvement either.

3) there is something more modern called "teaming" but I couldn't understand if for my purpose, it is equivalent